# Getting nosuchelement Exception

Tags: java

```
public class Vowcon {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
        int vcount1=0 , ccount1=0;
        int vcount2=0 , ccount2=0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t_case = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i=0; i<t_case+1; i++) {
            String str1 = sc.next();
            String str2 = sc.next();

            for(int j=0;j<str1.length();j++) {
                if(str1.charAt(j)=='a'||str1.charAt(j)=='e'||str1.charAt(j)=='i'||str1.charAt(j)=='o'||str1.charAt(j)=='u') {
                    vcount1++;
                }else if(str1.charAt(j)>='a'||str1.charAt(j)<='z') {
                    ccount1++;
                }
            }

            for (int k=0; k<str2.length(); k++) {
                if(str2.charAt(k)=='a'||str2.charAt(k)=='e'||str2.charAt(k)=='i'||str2.charAt(k)=='o'||str2.charAt(k)=='u') {
                    vcount2++;
                }else if(str2.charAt(k)>='a'||str2.charAt(k)<='z') {
                    ccount2++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(vcount1 + " " + ccount1 + " " + vcount1*ccount1);
            System.out.println(vcount2 + " " + ccount2 + " " + vcount2*ccount2);
        }
        sc.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    }
}
```

It is my code and I wanted to know why I am getting this exception . and can anybody help to resolve this exception. Please help me to resolve this problem

Comment: Can you add the Exception stacktrace?

Comment: Can you please describe what your code is doing and which results you expect from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are attempting to access the index of the string that is not reachable. Try `str2.length() - 1 ;`